# How to count the number of views the page seen by the users?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I am just doing a Q&A web app like SO. I want to count the number of views the page viewed by the user like SO `12 views`.

I used loopback as a server and i have a model questions which contain numberOfViews property. Here is the problem that i faced, by default loopback generates /questions/{id} endpoint and this endpoint finds the question by id and returns it but in addition to returning the question i want to increment the numberOfViews property of the question. How to accomplish that?

```
questions model

[
  {
    "title": "string",
    "body": "string",
    "tags": [
      "string"
    ],
    "date": "string",
    "numberOfViews" : 0,
    "questionerId": "string",
    "answers": [
      "string"
    ],
    "voteNumber": 0,
    "shortComments": [
      "string"
    ],
    "usersUpVoted": [
      "string"
    ],
    "usersDownVoted": [
      "string"
    ],
    "id": "string"
  }
]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `hook` for this purpose.

```
MyModel.observe('access', function logQuery(ctx, next) {
  console.log('Accessing %s matching %s', ctx.Model.modelName, ctx.query.where);
  next();
});
```

Note:

> You can check what you get in `ctx` and use your custom condition in `observe` to fulfill your requirement. As i have not test it.

reference link : [github](https://gist.github.com/bajtos/b8157112452eeaf984c9) , [document](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Operation-hooks.html)

Comment: Thanks @IfekharDani. I will let you soon.

Comment: Here is the problem @IfekharDani. When ever you perform, count,deleteAll, updateAll and exists, operations access observer will trigger but that is not the case.

Comment: Ya, I mention that you write some custom logic in observer to handle findbyid method...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to increment the numberOfViews property only on "findById" remote method better to use after remote hook:

```
  Model.afterRemote('findById', (ctx, result, cb) => {
    // You code here...
  });
```

Or the same using async/await (you should return promise here, or you code freeze)

```
  Model.afterRemote('findById', async (ctx, result) => {
    // You code here...
  });
```